# TypeORM NestJS: Best approach to manage database sharding using MySQL/RDMS?

Tags: express, sequelize.js, nestjs, typeorm, sharding

I managed database sharding using sequelize and express app like below,

- Create connections on bootup.
- Used hash key based(hash ring) algorithm to get the partition on insert/query data.
- e.g `model.getPartition(userId).get({...})`

Looking for the suggestion to handle it using NestJS/Typescript/TypeORM.

Comment: Instead of TypeORM, I used ObjectionJS which is based on KnexJS and did the same thing described above.

Comment: Can you please point me to an example to achieve sharding through this?